# Is gl_FragDepthEXT supported by Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I was trying to use gl_FragDepthEXT in a shader but ran into issues. Is there something I have to do to enable this extension?

Comment: I had a look, don't think its supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your hardware that determines if an extension is supported or not. So what you can do is query the hardware to see if the extension is supported. If you look in the source of three.js (src/renderers/webgl/WebGLExtensions.js), there are helper function to determine if an extension is supported:

```
// assuming here that _gl is the webgl context

var extensions = new THREE.WebGLExtensions( _gl );

// the return value is null if the extension is not supported,
// or otherwise an extension object 
extensions.get( "gl_FragDepthEXT" );
```

or in pure webGL:

```
// returns an array of strings, one for each supported extension
// for informational purposes only
var available_extensions = _gl.getSupportedExtensions();

// the return value is null if the extension is not supported,
// or otherwise an extension object 
var object_ext = _gl.getExtension( "gl_FragDepthEXT" );
```

Comment: Thanks I checked and it seems my hardware does support this extension. I have too further questions. Is there a way to get an idea how well supported this extension is? I'm really concerned with mobile support. And I was looking at the spec it states it has to be enabled. "The built-in varible gl_FragDepthEXT is optional, and must be enabled by #extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable

    before being used." Where would I have to put that code?

Comment: You cannot get an idea of how well an extension is supported. Either it is supported or not. The calls to `extensions.get()` the `_gl.getExtension()` enable the extension but you can also use that code in the fragment shader that uses it.

Comment: Cool thanks for the info. I guess I should not have said "how well supported this extension is". What I really meant was, is there a way to figure out how widespread the support is. Like do most mobile device support the extension.

Comment: I do not know of any database that holds that info.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are missing one requirement, when you are using a raw shader you must enable with the following string in your shader code:

"#extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable"

When using a THREE.ShaderMaterial the program string is partly auto-generated therefore the above string cannot be added early enough in your shader strings to avoid a shader compiler error so you enable with:

material.extensions.fragDepth = true

This will make gl_FragDepthEXT available as a fragment shader output if the extension is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question from the comments above, re: how well extension is supported. You can check http://webglstats.com/ to get a idea of webgl extensions currently supported by Devices/OS/Browser. The data comes from visitors on the participating websites only, but it should give you a general idea.